# Is Handsontable free to use?

Tags: jquery

We are planning to move one of our Excel application to Online and give some flexibility for the user to have the online tool with few excel features. I was looking into this Handsontable jquery plug-in and wanted to know if it can be used directly by just putting jquery reference.
Is there any licence required if it is used in an organization?

Comment: Check the documentation at the website.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues, not programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handsontable has [MIT license](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/blob/master/LICENSE) so you can use it freely

Comment: There seems to be two version of Handsontable. Pro version is not "free"  - https://handsontable.com/pricing.html, and free version is still MIT - https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable.

Comment: See also https://docs.handsontable.com/0.21.0/tutorial-licensing.html and http://docs.handsontable.com/0.26.1/tutorial-features.html for comparison between pro and free version.